# Event handlers of all controls invoked automatically on selectedIndexChange of dropdown in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I am stuck in a mysterious problem. I am searching from past 3 days but unable to get solution. I am working on a web application. In my web page I've 4 dropdown which are disable by default(I made Enabled = false at design time) and `AutoPostBack = true`. But enable on certain condition based on selected value of 5TH dropdown. When I select Item from 5TH dropdown then its `selectedIndexChanged` event get fired. Until this all is well. But when I select item 2nd time from 5TH dropdown then after it's `selectedIndexChanged` event all `selectedIndexChanged` events of other 4 dropdowns invoked too whereas these events are not supposed to excute. only the `selectedIndexChanged` event of 5th dropdown should execute.

Kindly help me why the event handler of other dropdowns are being executed too. I wrapped the whole form in an update panel.

Comment: can you  post  your code?

Comment: Sounds like you've wired them all to the same event handler. Post code please friend.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of research I fixed this problem. Actually them problem that in SelectedIndexChanged of 5TH DropDownList I was changing the values of other 4 DropDownLists. Therefore SelectedIndexChanged of other 4 DropDownLists become pending in event queue and on any next postback (in my case it occurred by changing value from 5th dropdownlist) these pending events also executes. Following link futher clears my concept.
[ASP.NET Web Server Control Event Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)